# Remove internal zero from paragraph numbering

Tags: numbering, sections-paragraphs

I'm writing a paper using the IEEE template. When using `\paragraph` I get a numbering that includes a zero in between. For example, this...

```
\paragraph{MSF\cite{rfc9033}} is the Minimal Scheduling Function, ...
```

... produces this ...

[image]

Is there a way to remove the zero in between so as to get `I-a` instead of `I-0a`?
Thanks!

Comment: `\paragraph` is the 4th level heading so should only be used after `\subsubsection`. If you only have three levels use `\subsection` not `\paragraph`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I presume you mean `\subsubsection` as the penultimate macro cited in your comment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes er yes, thanks

Comment: What IEEE template? Please, make the example self-contained and compilable.